# Best way to change 20 to 200 separate pixels in a large texture in webgl?

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl, framebuffer

So I'm trying to figure out the fastest way I can change for example 200 separate pixels(each with unique colors and in different locations) in a texture using webgl.

Is it possible to pass in the coordinates and color values to the shader so that it can do it in one pass? Or is there some limit that would prevent being able to do this?

Comment: Dont 100% understand what you are trying to do, but there is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texSubImage2D.

Comment: to clarify a bit- I have a large texture, and need to change various pixels within it.
So I'd have a list of coordinates, and new color values; (x:5,y:65)=rgb(1,20,50) , (x:45,y:8)=rgb(10,50,70) , ...etc 
I've been researching and It seems like I'd have to store this in another texture, and use a for loop to cycle through the data? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Yeah you just use `.texSubImage2D`. See other comment for details.

Comment: thanks! I tried the texSubImage2D, and it works. :) posted an answer below with the code.
I noticed that rendering gets slower the more calls you make to texSubImage2D per render cycle. The texture I'm modifying is 4096x4096, so maybe that is why? 
This will probably be alright, but If anyone knows how to speed it up, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

WaclawJasper suggested using .texSubImage2D,
Here's how I am using it.

```
var dataTypedArray = new Uint8Array(4); // Don't need to do this if the data is already in a typed array
    dataTypedArray[0] = 0;
    dataTypedArray[1] = 0;
    dataTypedArray[2] = 255;
    dataTypedArray[3] = 255;

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, posX, posY, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, dataTypedArray);
```